# putting an image in the XY plane of a matlab 3D scatter graph

Tags: matlab

I am trying to put an image on the XY plane of a 3D scattergraph. The current version that I have is giving some results but the image's colours is not showing properly.

Currently, I read the image as a grayscale in, but ideally I would like to have my points above a colour image.

```matlab
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11];
y = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
z = [0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,0,0,0];



min_x = min(min(x));
min_y = min(min(y));
max_x = max(max(x));
max_y = max(max(y));


planeimg = rgb2gray(imread('1.jpg'));



figure; hold on;



scatter3(x,y,z);


colormap(gray);

 minplaneimg = min(min(planeimg)); % find the minimum
scaledimg = (floor(((planeimg - minplaneimg) ./ ...
    (max(max(planeimg)) - minplaneimg)) * 255)); % perform scaling



imgzposition = -10;
 colorimg = ind2rgb(scaledimg,jet(256));


surf([min_x max_x],[min_y max_y],repmat(imgzposition, [2 2]),...
   colorimg,'facecolor','texture')

view(45,30);


xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
```